# PollableChannel with Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-annotations, spring-messaging

I have an interface **Channels.java**

```
    final String OUTPUT = "output";

    final String INPUT = "input";


    @Output(OUTPUT)
    MessageChannel output();

    @BridgeFrom(OUTPUT)
    PollableChannel input();
```

I have another class where i perform all the messaging operations:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(Channels.OUTPUT)
private MessageChannel Output;
```

I am able to send messages to the exchanges fine. How to I use my PollableChannel here? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

And how to I access the bean inside my @Component class?

I now have @Configuration class with

```
@Bean
@BridgeTo(Channels.OUTPUT)
public PollableChannel polled() {
    return new QueueChannel();
}
```

Want to be able to use this channel to receive messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bridge has to be a `@Bean` not an annotation on an interface method - see [the answer to your general question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44016599/spring-how-to-configure-messaging-bridge-poller-with-annotations/44026053#44026053).

**EDIT**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class So44018382Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So44018382Application.class, args);
        Thread.sleep(60_000);
        context.close();
    }

    @RabbitListener(bindings =
            @QueueBinding(value = @Queue(value = "foo", autoDelete = "true"),
                            exchange = @Exchange(value = "output", type = "topic"), key = "#"))
    // bind a queue to the output exchange
    public void listen(String in) {
        this.logger.info("received " + in);
    }

    @BridgeTo(value = Source.OUTPUT,
            poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "2"))
    @Bean
    public PollableChannel polled() {
        return new QueueChannel(5);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            polled().send(new GenericMessage<>("foo" + i));
            this.logger.info("sent foo" + i);
        }
    }

}
```

This works fine for me; the queue has a depth of 5; when it is full, the sender blocks; the poller only removes 2 messages at a time and sends them to the output channel.

This example also adds a rabbit listener to consume the messages sent to the binder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can i still create a Bean for the bridge and use Channels.OUTPUT for the @BridgeFrom?

Comment: Yes; it's just a bean name.

Comment: Kindly see EDIT

Comment: Just auto wire it `@Autowired public PollableChannel polled`.

Comment: @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "polled") doesn't run.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do, but it works fine for me - I updated the answer with an example.